# How to make generate Custom ID for employee in django using different String

Tags: python, django

I have model's like this :

```
class Karyawan(models.Model):
  id_karyawan = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True,null=True)
  nama_karyawan = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  jabatan = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  branch_id = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
  agen_id = models.ForeignKey(Agen, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
  salary = models.IntegerField()
  alamat_karyawan = models.TextField()
  tanggal_masuk = models.DateField(null=True)
  kota_karyawan = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
  ttl_karyawan = models.DateField(null=True)
  tanggal_resign = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
  no_hp_karyawan = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  slug_karyawan = AutoSlugField(populate_from='id_karyawan')
```

I want id_karyawan filled using branch_id at first then following id using unique id like 'BDO001','BDO002', 'JKT001' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override **save** method for model class

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id_karyawan:
        self.id_karyawan = self.branch_id + self.id
    super(Karyawan,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Follow [overriding model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).